How can I unlock a locked amount in a liquidity mining pool ? It is now showing in my wallet after I revoked the token
I’ve joined a mining pool in DApp browser inside Trustwallet app then I tried to withdraw the money to my other wallet but I couldn’t because of the follwowing error
(Fail with error 'BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance') Error occurred during contract execution
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
BEP-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender.
Then the amount disappeared

I have the same. I had exact the same with USDT bep20 and i do not see it in my trustWallet anymore but only in the mining pool. I tried to get it withdrawen as well and i tried even before it was locked but i got trying swapping the usdt to bsb but i got smart contract errors. If you had an answer let me know. Trustwallet you can reach via support and pit on a support ticket. You can go to reddit as well where this topic is being handled.
